# How can I reset both scores to 0 once 10 is reached?

Tags: javascript

New to coding but I'm trying to reset my Rock Paper Scissors game back to zero after 10 tries.

I have this code here. When I play and one of them reaches 10, they don't reset:

```
function reset(userScore, computerScore) {
  return = 0;
}

function gameEnd() {
  if (userScore || computerScore === "10");
  return reset;
}
```

Comment: Your last if says "if userScore is any truthy value or computerScore is the string '10'". I doubt this is what you want.

Comment: Change `if (userScore ===10  || computerScore === "10");`

Answer (score 1):

I dont see where `reset` is setting the scores to zero. Also you don't need to accept userScore or computerScore as arguments unless you'll be using them in the function. Also, javascript doesn't mandate a return for void functions.

```
function reset() {
  userScore = 0;
  computerScore = 0;
}

function gameEnd() {
  // check both scores to see if either are 10
  // + will type cast a string to int (or keep an int) to check to see if 10
  if (+userScore === 10 || +computerScore === 10) {
    reset();
  }
}
```

Comment: You should use `==` not `===`, since `===` checks also for the type of the operands, meaning userScore and computerScore must be strings too.

Comment: False, Im checking strictly for it to be an int of 10, and typecasting strings to ints.

Comment: You edited your answer, before this you had your conditions like this: `userScore === "10" || computerScore === "10"`.  Anyway, they're okay now.

Answer (score 0):

The condition `if (userScore || computerScore === "10");` is incorrect and should be:

```
if (userScore === "10" || computerScore === "10")
```

But this means that both `userScore` and `computerScore` are strings. They should be numbers, in which case the condition should be:

```
if (userScore === 10 || computerScore === 10)
```

Also, why does the `reset()` function have two parameters that are not used? You should call it, not return it.

Try this:

```
function reset() {
  userScore = 0;
  computerScore = 0;
  return = 0;
}

function gameEnd() {
  if (userScore === 10 || computerScore === 10)
    return reset();
}
```

If the `gameEnd()` doesn't need to return anything, then `reset()` doesn't need to return anything either:

```
function reset() {
  userScore = 0;
  computerScore = 0;
}

function gameEnd() {
  if (userScore === 10 || computerScore === 10)
    reset();
}
```

Comment: You should be comparing numbers not strings.

Comment: @Turnip That's what the OP had and I don't know if they're strings or numbers. I added a note about that.

Answer (score 0):

If you want both to be 10 (and 10 is an integer):

```
function gameEnd() {
    if (userScore === 10 && computerScore === 10) {
        userScore = 0;
        computerScore = 0;
    }
}
```

If your goal is to check for just one of the two replace `&&` (AND) with `||` (OR)

I'd however recommend to use `>=` instead of `===` if you ever implement a "bonus" or whatever that gives two points and one has already 9, it will still get caught.

Note: I'm assuming `userScore` and `computerScore` are in a global scope.

A alternative would be:

```
function reset() {
    userScore = 0;
    computerScore = 0;
}

function gameEnd() {
    if (userScore >= 10 && computerScore >= 10) {
        reset();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use method reset() for making score to be 0. and before callin it in endGame method check if any of scores reaches 10 or not

```
function reset(){userscore=0; computerscore=0;}
function endGame(){
if(userscore >=10 ||computerscore>=0){
reset();
}
```